# Excel Equation for average of VLOOKUPS if the are not equal to 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array of data that I need to average for three columns based on a VLookup.  However, some of the rows do not have values in all three columns.  I do not want the zeros in those rows to skew the averages.  Does anyone know how I can modify this equation?

```
 =averageif(VLOOKUP(B:B,$C:$F,4,0)&VLOOKUP(B:B,$C:$F,3,0)&VLOOKUP(B:B,$C:$F,2,0),"<>0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just use `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`. If not, then probably you could keep results of `VLOOKUP` in some range and then use `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF` on this range to achieve desired result.